# How can I lock the zoom level in a Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have asked before how to get the actual zoom level, cause I was trying to change the maxZoom and minZoom to that current zoom but I can't change those parameters once I have declared them:

```
<Map className="map-layer" 
          center={center} 
          onoverlayadd={this.overlayadd} 
          onoverlayremove={this.overlayremove}
          ondragend={this.zoomChange}
          onzoomend={() => console.log(this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.getZoom())}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
          ref={this.mapRef}
          preferCanvas={false}
          animate={true}
          maxZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.getZoom() : 10}
          minZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.getZoom() : 1}
          >
```

I have also try to disable all the ways to change the zoom, but the zoomControl don't change once I have declared it, just like the max and min zoom.

```
<Map className="map-layer" 
          center={center} 
          onoverlayadd={this.overlayadd} 
          onoverlayremove={this.overlayremove}
          ondragend={this.zoomChange}
          onzoomend={() => console.log(this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.getZoom())}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
          ref={this.mapRef}
          preferCanvas={false}
          animate={true}
          scrollWheelZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? false : true}
          doubleClickZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? false : true}
          touchZoom={this.state.zoomLock ? false : true}
          zoomControl={this.state.zoomLock ? false : true}
          >
```

And those are the buttons that change the zoomLock state:

```
{
    this.state.zoomLock ? 
            <button onClick={ () => { this.setState({ zoomLock:false }); }  } type="button" className="btn btn-outline-dark">Zoom Lock: ON</button>
    :
            <button onClick={ () => { this.setState({ zoomLock:true }); }  } type="button" className="btn btn-outline-dark">Zoom Lock: OFF</button>
}
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-setminzoom

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks so much, that solve my problem. :')

Answer (score 0):

To disable zooming completly you can throw a error in the `zoomstart` event:

```
var zoomLock = false; //true



map.on("zoomstart", function(e) {
  if(zoomLock){
    throw 'zoom disabled';
  }
});
```